# How can I remove a merge candidate from the Merge tool in Team System?

Tags: tfs

In Team System, I have a file that was changed in branch ServicePack\2.1 (which was branched from Integration) and I don't want to merge it to Integration.  How do I delete it from the potential changeset list when I try to merge selected changesets?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove candidate #1234...

```
tf merge ServicePack\2.1 Integration /r /version:1234~1234 /discard
tf checkin
```

Comment: Is this usable from the TFS Visual Studio 2010 UI?

Comment: Does this `/discard` option really work? Because when I run this command, changes occur in Pending Changes, as if I've performed a merge operation manually.

Comment: @Anar Khalilov: Yes, it does. There are changes, but it is always “Keep Target Branch Version” (KeepYours).

Comment: Make sure that you execute the command from within a mapped folder!

Comment: Is there anyway to undo a `discard`?

Answer (score 7):

In Team Foundation Server 2010, you can discard changesets from a merge with this syntax:

```
tf merge "$/[Source Branch]" "$/[Target Branch]" /r /version:[Version] /discard
```

Answer (score -5):

While you can't "delete" a merge candidate, it is possible, when merging that file, to select the "accept target version" option.

This will mark the file as merged, but not make any changes to the target.  While not the most elegant of solutions it'll do what you need.

Comment: Even if there are not conflicts?

Comment: I see what you mean.  I can't see how you can do that in an elegant way, but you can do the merge as normal and then overwrite that file with the contents of the target branch on checkin.

TFS needs to support this use case the way Perforce does.

Comment: This is a dangerous.  Even if you are careful to preserve the file contents exactly, TFS won't record the merge history as AcceptYours.